# How to exclude a folder with remove-item cmdlet

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a git repository that I'm trying to delete all files and folders out of but not the `.git` folder. I've tried various permutations of the `-exclude` parameter but can't seem to get it.

`$repoPath = "c:\myrepo"`
`Remove-Item $repoPath -Recurse -Force -Exclude .git`
`Remove-Item $repoPath -Recurse -Force -Exclude *.git*`
`Remove-Item $repoPath -Recurse -Force -Exclude *.git`

No matter what I try the .git folder gets deleted. Any suggestions?

Comment: Won't `Remove-Item $repoPath` remove the entire folder? Don't you mean do use `Remove-Item $repoPath\*`?

Comment: Yup, that was it. I was removing the top level folder instead of everything underneath of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Remove-Item $repoPath` will remove the entire folder. Don't you mean do use `Remove-Item $repoPath\*`?